# How can I call a method on a handler created by logging.config.dictConfig in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, log-rotation

I'm trying to set up a particular logging scheme for an application I'm building. For it, I want to be able to rotate logs arbitrarily on a custom condition. As such, the built-in options of rotating based on time (using `TimedRotatingFileHandler`) or log size (using `RotatingFileHandler`) are not sufficient. Both `TimedRotatingFileHandler` and `RotatingFileHandler` do however have the method `doRollover` which I could use to implement what I want. The problem comes from that I'm using `logging.config.dictConfig` to set up my log configuration, like so:

```
config = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default_formatter": {
            "format": logging.BASIC_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "NOTSET",
            "formatter": "default_formatter",
            "backupCount": 5,
            "filename": "log.txt",
            "encoding": "utf8",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "level": "NOTSET",
            "handlers": ["file"],
        },
    },
}
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

This way, `logging.config.dictConfig` is responsible for instantiating `RotatingFileHandler`, and so I never get the chance to retain a reference to the class instance (i.e., the object). As such, it is not clear how I could go about calling methods upon the object.

How could I go about calling a method (in my case, `doRollover`) on an object instantiated as a handler by `logging.config.dictConfig`? Alternatively, if that is not possible, how can I manually provide a handler object that I have instantiated by calling the constructor directly given this configuration?

Comment: I think you just want a custom subclass of `BaseRotatingHandler` whose `rotator` attribute contains the logic for when to roll over, rather than trying to call `doRollover` or `rotate` yourself.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, that could've been a solution as well. I just found a solution that worked for me and posted an answer  but thanks for the suggestion regardless!

Comment: Added a better-researched version of my comment as an answer, in case anyone finds it interesting (or useless, if they want to downvote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by assessing the `handlers` property of the logger the handler is installed onto. In the code snippet above, the root logger is assigned the handler, and so we can get it like so:

```
file_handler_name = "file"
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

file_handler = next(
    handler for handler in root_logger.handlers if handler.name == file_handler_name
)
file_handler.doRollover()  # or whatever other method you want to call
```

This works because in the question's example, the handler is named "file", and in here we essentially iterate through `root_logger.handlers` until we find one where the `name` property is equal to "file". The handler returned by this iteration is then the object that was instantiated by `logging.config.dictConfig`.

If using `next` isn't to your liking, the equivalent with a for-loop would be this:

```
file_handler_name = "file"
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

for handler in root_logger.handlers:
    if handler.name == "file":
        file_handler = handler
        break

file_handler.doRollover()  # or whatever other method you want to call
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for if and when to perform a rollover is encoded in `BaseRotatingHandler.emit`:

```
 def emit(self, record):
    try:
        if self.shouldRollover(record):
            self.doRollover()
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
    except Exception:
        self.handleError(record)
```

You can define a custom subclass of `BaseRotatingHandler` or `RotatingFileHandler`, as appropriate, whose `__init__` method can take additional arguments provided by the configuration dictionary and whose `shouldRollover` can use those arguments to implement your rollover logic.

For example,

```
class NewbytesHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, *, foo, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.foo = foo

    def shouldRollover(self, record):
        if <some logic involving self.foo>:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and in your configuration,

```
config = {
    ...
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "class": "NewbytesHandler",
            "level": "NOTSET",
            "formatter": "default_formatter",
            "foo": 7,
            "filename": "log.txt",
            "encoding": "utf8",
        },
    },
    ...
}
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```